# future/promise: pickup or delivery?

Tags: design-patterns, concurrency, language-agnostic

I'm trying to implement a simple futures module and originally I modeled it after c++'s `std::future` in that a `promise` holds a value and possibly many `futures` can retrieve it. So basically (if I am understanding it correctly), the `promise` says "I'll have a value ready for you to pickup" and the `future` picks it up when it is ready.

I've run into a situation where I feel it would be better for the caller to provide some kind of output buffer with a flag, and have the responding thread fill the buffer, then set the flag. So this is no longer future/promise, but something inverted, where the `future` says "deliver this value to me" and the `promise` leaves a notification when it has done so.

I don't know how to go about looking for more information about this pattern. Does it have a name?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but: would you consider making your function accept a buffer as an argument and return a promise for a flag for whether the buffer was filled successfully? This would be a promise-shaped variant of the standard pattern of passing a pointer as a parameter and returning a status code.

Comment: Unfortunately not, though I do like this solution. The problem is that I want to put the result's lifetime directly under the caller's control, without the responder having to maintain anything but a task queue. Putting smart pointers to the flags inside the futures would work, but would either complicate the responder-side memory handling logic or incur lots of little heap allocations. Right now my entire shared memory management strategy comes down to a call to "buffer.swap ()" and I'm trying to keep it that way for as long as possible.